# Google Apps Script UrlFetchApp.fetch converts integers to floats?

Tags: google-apps-script, urlfetch

I am writing a Google App Script that accesses several APIs using UrlFetchApp

One of my API POST requests expects an integer value in the payload, but UrlFetchApp.fetch changes the integer value (i.e. 0) to a float (i.e. 0.0)

My options look something like this:

```
const options = { method: 'POST', headers: {...}, payload: { someStringA: "foo", someStringB: "bar", App: 0 } }
```

And the error msg returned from the API is:

```
{"message":"The request is invalid.","modelState":{"request.App":["The value '0.0' is not valid for App.","The App field is required."]}}
```

UrlFetchApp.fetch has converted my App value of: 0 to: 0.0 which this API endpoint does not accept.

I tried forcing the request value to a string "0" instead, but the API does not accept a string type for that property.

Does anyone know of a workaround for this? How can I tell UrlFetchApp.fetch to keep integer values "as is" and not convert them to floats?

ps. the same request works ok for me via cURL like this:

```
curl --location --request POST "https://$url" \
    --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    --header "Authorization: Bearer $token" \
    --data "{\"someStringA\":\"$foo\",\"someStringB\":\"$bar\",\"app\":0}"
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance

UPDATE: apologies, but the problem here was not with UrlFetchApp after all. My problem was that the response coming back from the api was an empty object and I was trying to log it like this: JSON.parse(response); resulting in the errors mentioned.

Comment: Can you provide the sample curl command you confirmed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question, unfortunately, I'm not sure about the specification of the API you want to use, your request header and your curl command you confirmed. So I would like to propose the following modification patterns as my guess.

#### From:

```
const options = { method: 'POST', headers: {...}, payload: { someStringA: "foo", someStringB: "bar", App: 0 } }
```

#### To: pattern 1

```
const options = { method: 'POST', headers: {...}, contentType: "application/json", payload: JSON.stringify({ someStringA: "foo", someStringB: "bar", App: 0 }) };
```

- In this case, the data is sent as JSON.
- If you are using `Content-Type` in `headers`, please remove it.

#### To: pattern 2

```
const options = { method: 'POST', headers: {...}, payload: JSON.stringify({ someStringA: "foo", someStringB: "bar", App: 0 }) };
```

- In this case, the data is sent as form data of the string value.

#### To: pattern 3

```
const options = { method: 'POST', headers: {...}, payload: { someStringA: "foo", someStringB: "bar", App: "0" } };
```

- In this case, `"0"` is sent as a string value of form data in the parsed data.

#### Note:

- If above modification patterns were not the solution of your issue, can you provide your sample curl command that you confirmed? By this, I would like to modify my answer.

#### Reference:

- [Class UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)

### Added:

From your curl command, I understood that my pattern 1 is the same request with your curl command. But from `Unexpected end of JSON input` of your replying, unfortunately, although I'm not sure about your current script using my pattern 1, when your curl command is converted to Google Apps Script, it becomes as follows. Can you test it again?

```
const token = "###";  // Please use your token.
const data = { someStringA: "foo", someStringB: "bar", App: 0 };
const options = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
  contentType: "application/json",
  payload: JSON.stringify(data)
};
const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch("your URL", options);
console.log(res.getContentText())
```

Comment: Many thanks for the suggestions: patterns 1 and 3 result in "SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input" and pattern 2 results in a "Truncated server response: {"message":"The request is invalid...". I have updated the original question with curl command.

Comment: @Richard Salt Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. From your added curl command, I confirmed that the pattern 1 is the same request with your curl command. But from your error message in your replying, can you provide your current script using my pattern 1? If you can do, please add it to your question. By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: @Richard Salt I added one more sample script which converted your curl command to Google Apps Script. Could you please confirm it? In this sample script, I think that the request is the same with your curl command. But if this didn't work. I apologize again.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike - thanks for your help, but I think I have wasted your time! The error messages I have been seeing are not coming from the UrlFetchApp.fetch command. My problem was that, immediately after my fetch, I was attempting to parse and log the response, like this: JSON.parse(response); however, the response object is empty, even though the post command was successful. So it is now working, based on your Pattern 1 solution above

Comment: @Richard Salt Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.